# Remove old date rows in R

Tags: r, date, time

I have table:

```
Date  | Column1 | Column2
------+---------+--------
6/1/1 | A       | 3
5/1/1 | B       | 4
4/1/1 | C       | 5
1/1/1 | A       | 1
7/1/1 | B       | 2
1/1/1 | C       | 3
```

I need table:

```
Date  | Column1 | Column2
------+---------+--------
6/1/1 | A       | 3
4/1/1 | C       | 5
7/1/1 | B       | 2
```

How to remove old rows based on two criteria (`Column1`, `Column2`)?

Comment: What are the criteria?

Answer (score 0):

Group by Dates, arrange in descending order within group, then keep the first row with `slice`, like this

```
library(dplyr)
ans <- df %>%
         group_by(Column1, Column2) %>%
         arrange(desc(as.Date(Date))) %>%   # will sort within group now
         slice(1) %>%              # keep first row entry of each group
         ungroup()
```

Your error is occurring because your date format is a bit funny. I recommend using `lubridate::parse_date_time` which is more robust than base R datetime functions

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
ans <- df %>%
         group_by(Column1, Column2) %>%
         arrange(desc(parse_date_time(Date, format="mdy"))) %>%   # will sort within group now
                                                                  # the date format is specified as month-day-year
         slice(1) %>%              # keep first row entry of each group
         ungroup()
```

**EDIT**

Based on helpful comment by @count, we can simplify dplyr chain to

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
ans <- df %>%
         group_by(Column1, Column2) %>%
         slice(which.max(parse_date_time(Date, format="mdy"))) %>%              # keep max-Date row entry of each group
         ungroup()
```

Comment: Group_by should based on Column1 ```group_by(Column1)```

Comment: Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Comment: You could use `slice(which.max(Date))` and go without the `arrange`.

Comment: If i have format YYYY-MM-DD, how change value in format=??

Comment: Error in slice_impl(.data, dots) : unused argument (format = "ymd")

Comment: Try this `group_by(Column1, Column2) %>% mutate(Date = parse_date_time(Date, format="ymd") %>% slice(which.max(Date))`